# Break in phrasal verb

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

[Source](http://www.english-test.net/lessons/53/index.html)

> Now, it so happened that Maggie owned a horse which ***had been broken***
>   ***in*** but was still a bit wild.

Honestly, I have no idea about the meaning of ***break in***. Maybe it stands for being almost domestic, but still a bit wild.

Didn't find anything useful in dictionaries.

Comment: If you google "break in horse", you'll find the meaning you're looking for.  Interestingly enough, the more common usage seems to be simply "breaking a horse", not "breaking *in* a horse".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [break in](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/break-in_1) means to **train a horse** (see No. 5 definition in the link).

The sentence could be rephrased to:

> Now, it so happened that Maggie owned a horse which was not **trained**
>   but was still a bit wild.

When you break in a horse, you don't mean you separate it into pieces as to break literally means. It metaphorically means you **interrupt a continuity of its wildness (being wild)** and get it domesticated or trained.

Many English idioms and phrases have metaphorical senses and you need to understand them on a case-by-case basis.

*Wild* is antonym of *trained* or *domesticated*.

Comment: *Break in* also has a more general meaning of "to use for the first couple times" for various purposes.  You can "break in" shoes (e.g. new shoes will typically be tight until you wear them a number of times), or a vehicle engine (e.g. you're supposed to drive a new car carefully for a while and change oil more frequently during that time), or similar.